# Merged list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the below list containing dictionaries, which themselves contain dataframes, that I would like to merge.

```
ls = [{'varID': 101, 'varDesc': 'Description of variable 101', 'values': df101},
      {'varID': 102, 'varDesc': 'Description of variable 102', 'values': df102},
      {'varID': 103, 'varDesc': 'Description of variable 103', 'values': df103}]
```

Where df101, df102, and df103 are all *x* by 1 dataframes in shape with date values as the index (named 'refPer'), and the column name of 'values' in all the dataframes. **Note:** that *x* is not the same size for all the dateframes.

I would like to merge the dataframes and have attempted the following:

```
mergedDF = reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x.get('values'),y.get('values'), how = 'outer', on = 'refPer'), ls)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` to join Dataframes of unequal length. You can also provide the parameter `keys` to give a name to each dataframe you are concatenating. You'll create a multiindex, but you can drop the original level if you don't want it:

```
df = pd.concat([x['values'] for x in ls], axis=1, keys=[x['varID'] for x in ls])
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)  # removes 'original' level
```

Comment: I get an error saying invalid syntax at the keys part.

Comment: This ended up working.

`mergedDF = pd.concat([x['values'] for x in ls], axis = 1, keys = 'refPer')`

Comment: @jmaval Great if you don't need the keys you can also just remove it. I don't know why the other method didn't work for you.